# How is it possible for GreatScott to use this MOSFET driver if it can only give 1.5 amps max?

Tags: mosfet, current, brushless-dc-motor, mosfet-driver

I am trying to follow this [tutorial by Greatscott](https://www.instructables.com/Make-Your-Own-Sensored-ESC/).

I don't understand how the TC4427 MOSFET driver he is using in this build works. I searched up the datasheet which can be found [here](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001422G.pdf). It says "High Peak Output Current: 1.5A". If this MOSFET Driver can only deliver 1.5 Amps how is it possible to use with a BLDC motor? While I don't know the exact current this BLDC motor uses I'm sure it has to be much higher than 1.5 Amps right?

What am I missing here? How is it possible to use this TC4427 MOSFET driver?

Comment: The MOSFETS actually driving the motor are the IRF5305 (P-channel) and IRFZ44N (N-channel).

Comment: If you watch the video, he clearly states that that is a rig to allow him to test his ebike motor with low voltages.  Probably not driving him!  In his next video, be switched back to the provided BLDC driver.  [EBike Battery Pack || DIY or Buy || Electric Bike Conversion (Part 2)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2sBhDxmPmA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TC4427 is a MOSFET driver, intended to drive the (capacitive) gate of a MOSFET, which in turn supplies current to the motor. Note the usage here in one leg of the design:

[image]

The driver turns the FETs on and off, and motor current flows through the body of the MOSFET.  The driver's relatively high current rating is so that it can charge the FET gate capacitance (and Miller capacitance) quickly to avoid excessive switching loss and potential shoot-through.

The driver does NOT supply current to the motor.